# javascript simualte choosing a file

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I am trying to make a java script that i can just enter in my browser and will automatically choose the file.

I know i can fill forms and such by using a script like `document.getElementById('user_name').value='admin';return false;`

But im not sure how to do it for choosing a file that i predefined for example in c:/file.txt . How would that work for something like the html below?

```
<input name="Configration_File" type="file" id="Configration_File">
```

Comment: Would you like to open a website on your computer which is accessing your local files? I don't think so. That's why you can't do this.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html

Comment: What are you trying to do, write an auto upload script? How do you intend to "enter the javascript in *your* browser"? If you're going to develop a browser extension, it might have additional privileges like choosing files from your disk.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be done, for security reasons.  Otherwise any website out there could secretly get access to your files.

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1696884/1462065) why this is not possible.

You could however help the user to find the file by specifying the accept attribute like this:

```
<input name="Configration_File" type="file" id="Configration_File"
accept=".txt,text/plain">
```